# React, getting index of list when clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to follow the examples that are coming up here on Stack Overflow and I can't get it to work.  It works just fine if I remove everything that says "index" though.  It passes in the "page" just fine.  Can someone point me in the correct decision please thank you.

My Click function

```
handleOnClick(page, index) {
    console.log(page);  //page is correct
    console.log(index); //undefined

}
```

My Render

```
let self = this;

    playlistList[pos].list.map(function(page, index)

    {if (page.selected) {
      return (
        <tr key={page.id} onClick={() => self.handleOnClick(page, index)}>
          <td>{page.name}</td>
          <td>{page.subComposition.name}</td>
        </tr>
      );}
    }
```

Comment: Your parameters are passed in backwards

Comment: @Ju66ernaut which parameters.  I reversed the handeClick parameters it doesn't work neither

Comment: handleOnClick(index, page) and you pass in page, index

Comment: @Ju66ernaut no matter how I order the parameters one of them is still undefined.  Im just having trouble passing the index

Comment: can you reproduce the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/zz0o2v0q/2/, I tried to repro it based on the code snippets you've provided but I'm not seeing the same behavior

Comment: ugh sorry everyone, you're right it was my typo.  i tried deleting the question cus it was my mess up but it wont let me.  sigh been at this for the past hour too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your function `handleOnClick` it's correct? I think the parameters are wrong.

When you call the function you pass `handleOnClick(page, index)`, and in the method the parameters are `handleOnClick(index, page)`

Comment: they should be the same now.  I tried reversing and as well just trying to see what comes out of it but still the index is undefined

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off making a component that handles creating the tr. Then creating the function in that component, then running the function using the props passed down.

Unless you're going to need to change the state, then pass the function down to the component to be used.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the parameters name in the arrow function parentesis, and it's value through the function parentesis.

Like:

```
onClick={(page, index) => self.handleOnClick(page, index)}
```